# How can I block a command from running in my terminal using zsh?

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I basically want to stop my computer from running this command on my terminal:

```
git checkout master
```

My first thought was adding an alias, but the alias will not grab the whole command just the first part.

Basically if I run the command I want to echo a message, nothing too fancy.

So I was wondering what was the best way of doing this?

Comment: You might want to look at this question regarding Git aliases that shadow built-in commands. Then you could define `checkout` as an alias that checks first to see if the branch being checked out is `master`, and only running the "real" `git commit` command if it is not.

Comment: Or, you might simply replace the branch head with a tag. This sounds like an XY problem, though: why do you want to prevent any specific branch from being checked out, let alone `master`?

Comment: As far as `zsh` is concerned, the *command* is `git`; the rest are just arguments. You could define a shell function that shadows `git` and checks its arguments before proceeding with the regular `git` command or doing something different, but this could require essentially duplicating `git`'s argument parsing.

Comment: yeah that's more or less what i was thinking of but I'm unsure of how to proceed to write a function that checks for the arguments. I thought there was some way to have sort of like a hook that would check all the commands incoming and if any of them are "git checkout master" then echo something otherwise proceed. I was just unsure how to proceed.

The reason why I don't want to allow to checkout master is because I don't have access to delete that branch and I keep checking out to it when I should be checking out the develop branch.

Comment: There is a `preexec` hook you can define, but it would just get, say, `git checkout master` as an argument, leaving you to spilt the command line up into separate arguments, then doing the same kind of logic you would with a function named `git` (except that function would already get `checkout` and `master` as separate arguments).

Comment: _I'm unsure of how to proceed to write a function that checks for the arguments._  Function arguments (positional parameters) are in `$1`, `$2` and so on. The array of all arguments are in `$*`. If your question boils down to "how to I process function arguments in zsh", I suggest that you ask for this a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The shadow function for `git` that @chepner suggested looks to be simple enough if you only need to handle a small set of parameters:

```bash
git(){
  if [[ "$1 $2" == "checkout master" ]]; then
    print "never mind"
    return 1
  fi
  =git "$@"
}
```